# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 4672: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, unicode

Estoy intentando leer un archivo de txt bastante grande pero lee unos cuantas miles de líneas y aparece este error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 4672: invalid continuation byte

He probado dentro de la función `open()` utilizar diferentes encodes pero nada.

Comment: ¿Has probado la codificación latin-1, ya que saca el mismo error normalmente?

Comment: ¿y si escribes `file nombrearchivo` en el terminal no te dice su codificación?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

un gusto en saludar

También podrías intentar indicando el parámetro ""**errors='ignore'**"" o cambiando el encoding (ASCII, UTF8, etc).

Acá te dejo dos opciones con las que yo abro archivos

```
with open('<ruta>/<archivo>.txt', encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as datos:
 f=datos
```

o también

```
f = open('myfile.txt', encoding="ascii", errors='ignore')
```

saludos y bienvenido a la comunidad

Comment: No explica la causa del error, sus posibles causas y soluciones.